# switch audio output from PA to jack, breaks audio on google-chrome

Tags: sound, google-chrome, pulseaudio, jack

I occasionally switch audio output from the ubuntu default `pulse-audio`  to `jack`.
this has created several problems that I haven't managed to fix in the past (no sound from `firefox` ever again, then switched to `chromium` which was fine), but now I am using `google-chrome` and whenever I switch on jack, I get no sound from the application. mind you, audio works fine from , say `jukebox`.

The steps I take to switch on jack are the following:

```
- run qjackctl
- start the audio server.
```

Note: usually the PA tp jack source and sink modules haven't been started (why, oh why?) so I fire up a console and type in :

```
pactl load-module module-jack-sink channels=2; pactl load-module module-jack-source channels=2; pactl set-default-sink jack_out; pactl set-default-source jack_in
```

there, now `jackd` is up and running.

Now, I fire `google-chrome` from command line, and see the following when I visit a page in youtube to see a video:

```
[22624:22645:1119/161906:ERROR:audio_manager_base.cc(422)] Not implemented reached in virtual std::string media::AudioManagerBase::GetDefaultOutputDeviceID()
```

Argh! any ideas?

Comment: I fought with a similar problem using ALSA.  For that, it was a question of creating a "default" alsa device (pcm.!default).  Perhaps something similar with an alsa loopback device would work (see: http://www.remastersys.com/forums/index.php?topic=2800.0).

Answer (score 0):

I had/have the same problems.

At the moment I have a workaround for it.

- stop jack
- start the player (youtube, webradio...)
- start jack
- in pavucontrol you can adjust the output of the app to the Jack Sink.

---

tried many possibilities. even the Cadence (from kxstudio) - "solution" didn't bring the suggested results...